# Variables order for ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

My dataframe:

```
Variable <- sample(-9:10)
Levels<-rep(c("N", "A", "L","B", "O", "C", "U", "R", "E", "Y" ),times=2)
ID<-rep(c("WT", "KO"), each=10)
df <- data.frame(Variable, Levels, ID)
```

I run ggplot and I get this:

[image]

If I had these two lines

```
df$ID=factor(df$ID, c("WT","KO"))
df$Levels=factor(df$Levels, c("N", "A", "L","B", "O", "C", "U", "R", "E", "Y" ))
```

I can get this

[image]

But there must be a way to do this without entering manually the levels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create your initial data frame with the correct factor, i.e.

```
df = data.frame(Variable, factor(Levels, levels=unique(Levels)), ID)
```

The `unique` function helpfully maintains the correct order. Alternatively,

```
levels = c("N", "A", "L","B", "O", "C", "U", "R", "E", "Y" )
Levels = factor(rep(levels, each=2), levels)
```